# Why can't we create a custom filter with only excluded tags?

Tags: feature-request, tags, search, filtering

I recently realized that there is no possibility to create customs filters with only excluded tags.

I'm wondering why there is this limitation as you can already, through the search field, search for results while only excluding tags.

The SE site where I would appreciate making such customs filters would be [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/). There are plenty of questions about Minecraft, but it's not just one tag, there's something like nearly 10 different tags usually used for these questions. 
As most of them are pretty lengthy, it's pretty tiring to write all of them in the search bar every time I want to check questions that are not linked in any way to Minecraft.

I could put all these Minecraft tags in ignored tags, but sometimes I also want to check these questions, so I'd like to avoid removing them from ignored, then put them back again when I don't want to see them anymore.

To some up, I'd like to be able to do something like this :
[image: Example of only excluded tags custom filter]

Is there any way we can get this functionality? Or is there a good reason for not?

Comment: I didn't understand what you meant at first, but I think I get it now. There's a "My watched tags" option in the create custom filter dialogue, but [no "my ignored tags" one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGF4b.png).

Comment: On a related note, you can use wildcards in tag filtering, including in the watch/ ignore lists. Eg. [\[\*minecraft\*\]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzOyq.png) will reference all tags with "minecraft" in their name, which is likely the vast majority of MC-related tags.

Comment: @zcoop98 It's more like I'd like to be able to only input tags to remove from the research in the "The following tags" section. Having a "my ignored tags" option would mean I'd still have to add/remove these from my ignored tags when I want to ^^ I'll try to add something to my question to make it clearer. Oh, didn't know that, thank you a lot ^^ I think I'll try to use these wildcards until we get someone more convenient ^^

Comment: You could toggle wether you want ignored tags to be greyed out, or completely hidden. In that way you could achieve what you want without setting watched tags I think.

Comment: @Luuklag That could be a workaround, but what if I want only some of the ignored tags to be visible again? Imagine if I had to set something like tens of ignored tags because I usually don't want to see them, but I want to see again only some of these while still ignoring others? It might be a bit nitpicking, but I'm pretty sure it could be of use to someone else too.

Comment: @Zoma toggle them to greyed out, amd do a search for that specific tag(s).